# Python check two dates inside date range

Tags: python, datetime, compare, conditional-statements

I need to check that two dates, not in any date range on the list.

I want to find out can user check-in in dates (check_range_true - can, check_range_false - can't) or this dates already booked (in date_ranges)

I have range looks like:

```
date_ranges = [
    ['2020-1-12', '2020-1-13'],
    ['2020-1-14', '2020-1-15'],
    ['2020-1-15', '2020-1-16'],
    ['2020-1-16', '2020-1-18'],
    ['2020-1-18', '2020-1-19'],
    ['2020-1-21', '2020-1-23'],
    ['2020-1-23', '2020-1-27'],
    ['2020-1-30', '2020-2-1'],
    ['2020-2-5', '2020-2-7'],
    ['2020-2-7', '2020-2-9'],
    ['2020-2-9', '2020-2-11'],
    ['2020-2-14', '2020-2-18'],
    ['2020-2-20', '2020-2-26'],
    ['2020-3-26', '2020-3-30'],
    ['2020-5-29', '2020-5-30'],
    ['2020-10-10', '2021-1-15']
]
```

And two dates (for example)

```
check_range_true = ['2020-02-02', '2020-02-04']
check_range_false = ['2020-02-02', '2020-02-05']
```

I know how check one date in range but not understand how to solve it with two dates.

What to the best way to check these dates in a range and got results, **True** for the first variable (because of 2020-02-02, 2020-02-04 not "touch" range) and **False** for the second variable (because of 2020-02-05 is in range of ['2020-2-5', '2020-2-7'])?

Comment: I want to find out can user check-in in dates (two variables) or this dates already booked ( in date_ranges)

Comment: Can you clarify whether check_range_true = ['2020-02-02', '2021-02-04'] should return true or not?

Comment: does this solve your problem?

Comment: I think no, sometimes got wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you what to do is to check the dates with (start < first_date < end) and (start < end_date < end) logic

```
date_ranges = [
    ['2020-1-12', '2020-1-13'],
    ['2020-1-14', '2020-1-15'],
    ['2020-1-15', '2020-1-16'],
    ['2020-1-16', '2020-1-18'],
    ['2020-1-18', '2020-1-19'],
    ['2020-1-21', '2020-1-23'],
    ['2020-1-23', '2020-1-27'],
    ['2020-1-30', '2020-2-1'],
    ['2020-2-5', '2020-2-7'],
    ['2020-2-7', '2020-2-9'],
    ['2020-2-9', '2020-2-11'],
    ['2020-2-14', '2020-2-18'],
    ['2020-2-20', '2020-2-26'],
    ['2020-3-26', '2020-3-30'],
    ['2020-5-29', '2020-5-30'],
    ['2020-10-10', '2021-1-15']
]
#convert to a flat list
date_ranges = [k for i in date_ranges for k in i]
#truncate the start and the end value    
date_ranges = date_ranges[1:-1]
#convert values to datetime
import datetime
date_ranges = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in date_ranges]
#create available time slots
date_ranges = [[date_ranges[i],date_ranges[i+1]] for i in range(0,len(date_ranges),2)]

#convert the check date to date time
check_range = ['2020-02-02', '2020-02-04']
check_range = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in check_range]

# apply the logic of start < date < end twice
any([(i[0] < check_range[0] < i[1]) and (i[0] < check_range[1] < i[1]) for i in date_ranges])
True

check_range = ['2020-02-02', '2020-02-05']
check_range = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in check_range]

any([(i[0] < check_range[0] < i[1]) and (i[0] < check_range[1] < i[1]) for i in date_ranges])

False
```

Comment: why need to do this step - date_ranges = date_ranges[1:-1] ?

Comment: to pull the available dates only. to convert this ```['2020-1-12', '2020-1-13'],
    ['2020-1-14', '2020-1-15']``` to this ```['2020-1-13','2020-1-14']```

Comment: It seems not to work correctly, for example – https://yadi.sk/i/uMEwOjyF66LOCw Your code tell i can book for dates from 24.01 to 26.01, but 25.01 already booked and this means I cant book in this range.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you want to check if given date range (e.g. `check_range_true`) overlaps (or not) with any other date range specified in the list. To achieve this, I would first transform string values to proper `datetime` objects for easier dates comparison. This could be achieved with list comprehension and `strptime`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

booked_date_ranges = [
    [datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')]
    for start_date, end_date in date_ranges
]
```

Then I would create a function, which would check if provided date range (consisting of start date, and end date) overlaps with any date range from the previously specified list. You need to check if start date is between date range or end date is between date range. It would be something along these lines:

```py
def dates_overlap(date_range_to_check, booked_date_ranges):
    dates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in date_range_to_check]
    return any(
        (start_date <= dates[0] and dates[0] <= end_date) or (start_date <= dates[1] and dates[1] <= end_date)
        for start_date, end_date in booked_date_ranges
    )
```

Then if you want to check if given date range DOES NOT overlap, you can just use the `dates_overlap` function and negate the result:

```py
>>> not dates_overlap(check_range_false, booked_date_ranges)
False
>>> not dates_overlap(check_range_true, booked_date_ranges)
True
```

I hope this answers your question. Of course this is just a draft and there's definitely some room for improvement, but should be a working solution to given problem.